# Silverlight project fails to compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, compilation

I have a Silverlight 3 project in VS2008.  Today, for whatever reason, I get an error when compiling.

`Configuration system failed to initialize`

It reports the error on Line 1, Column 1 for every .xaml file in the project.

I did a repair on VS2008, reinstalled all the Silverlight 3 bits (e.g. SDK, VS2008 tools and the Controls Toolkit), but the problem still persists.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code control for the project, please roll back to a previous change set and see if it works in VS still.

I suspect your project was corrupt for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Might be something that messed up your visual studio installation. If code is not a problem , then you can try system Restore.